# Javascript issue- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'incart' of undefined whenever I click delete icon

Tags: javascript

Whenever I click on delete ion-icon to delete items from the cart page, the console log gives me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘incart’ of undefined Can anyone help me with this issue?
console.log(cartItems[productName].price + " " + cartItems[productName].incart); ---  I can see the error at this line.

```
function displayCart() {  
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');  
cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);  


let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products"); 
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

//console.log(cartItems);---pulling data from localstorage

console.log(cartItems); 

if(cartItems && productContainer) {

    productContainer.innerHTML ='';
    Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
    productContainer.innerHTML +=   
        `
        <div class="products">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>

         <span>${item.name}</span>            


    <div class="price">$${item.price},00</div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <ion-icon name="caret-back-circle-outline">Remove</ion-icon>

        <span>${item.incart}</span> 
        <ion-icon name="caret-forward-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
    $${item.incart * item.price},00 
    </div>
    </div>
        `
    ;
    });

    productContainer.innerHTML += 
        `
        <div class="basketTotalContainer">
        <h4 class="basketTotalTitle"> Basket Total </h4>
        <h4 class ="basketTotal"> 
            $${cartCost},00
        </h4> 
    </div>

        `;          
   }  
     deleteButtons();   //calling the function here
   }

   function deleteButtons() { 

    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.products ion-icon'); //products class name
    let productName;
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers')
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');   
    console.log(cartItems);

    for(let i=0; i < 10; i++)    
    {

   //AddEventListener is working whenever I click on the icon.
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');    
    console.log(productName);
    console.log(cartItems[productName].price + " " + cartItems[productName].incart); 
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers',productNumbers - cartItems[productName].incart); 
    localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - (cartItems[productName].price * 
    cartItems[productName].incart));
    delete cartItems[productName];
    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));      
    });     }
   }
```

Comment: What you see when `console.log(cartItems);` in deleteButtons()

Comment: I see data   as   {naturalStraight: {…}}
naturalStraight:
incart: 4
name: "Natural Straight"
price: 95
tag: "naturalStraight"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: can anyone help me this issue?